# NSString comparison question

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to test to see if an NSString has the letters "PDF" as the first 3 letters:

```
if ([[[profiles stringForKey:@"response"] characterAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"P"]) {
            //TODO
        }
```

I started with this approach to see if I could at least narrow it down to those strings that start with "P" but I am getting an error on this that reads: "Invalid receiver type 'unichar'" AND "Cast to pointer from integer of different size"

Am I getting these errors because I am using the isEqualToString comparison?  Does that attach the terminating zero to "P"?  I tried to use the "==" comparison but I was also getting an error with that method.

Comment: Well, `characterAtIndex` does not return a `NSString` but a `unichar` and this type probably has no method `isEqualToString`. This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354388/unichar-and-nsstring-how-interchangeable-are-these

Comment: Not probably; it doesn't.  A `unichar` is a primitive type and thus cannot have methods.  Fortunately, `NSString` has better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ([profiles hasPrefix:@"PDF"]) {
  NSLog(@"my string starts with \"PDF\"");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the method substringToIndex instead of characterAtIndex. characterAtIndex is returning a unichar which is not an objective-c object to which isEqualToString can be sent.

Here is something that worked for me:

```
NSString*   testString  = @"PDFDocument";
NSString*   subString   = [testString substringToIndex:3];

if ( [subString isEqualToString:@"PDF"] == YES )
{
    NSLog( @"same" );
}
```

Comment: +1 except that this would fail with multi-byte-character languages.