# Porting Javascript string building code to Objective C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, porting

I have this code in Javascript:

```
var f = chr(50) + chr(0) + chr(1) + chr(64) + chr(24) + chr(0) + chr(0) + chr(1) + chr(159) + chr(13) + chr(0) + chr(0) + chr(224) + chr(7);

function chr(AsciiNum) {
    return String.fromCharCode(AsciiNum);
}
```

`console.log` outputs this as

```
2@
à
```

With a length of 14.

I am trying to port it to Objective C.
I tried doing the following:

```
NSString *f = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",50, 0 ,1, 64 , 24 , 0 , 0 , 1, 159,  13 , 0 , 0 , 224 , 7];
```

But I received a different output to the javascript code when using NSLog:

```
2@ü
```

What am I doing wrong? Is a character set issue?

Comment: What are you expecting to get printed? As far as I can see the output seems right in Objective-C compared to the ascii values on http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Could it be that you need to use the unichar literal %C?

Comment: Just FYI in JavaScript you can pass a list of characters to `String.fromCharCode()` - you don't have to call it one character at a time.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, this is a simplification of an issue but thanks :)

Comment: @CodaFi - I dont think so. That only outputs 2 to the console and the base64 encoded value is different from Javascript

Comment: @CodaFi - Actually you seem to get me aq lot closer to the required strings, so thanks for that, but its still not right!

Comment: I've been trying and trying various ASCII char combinations for a while now, and I just don't think NSLog is quite capable of expressing the string.  Render it in a UILabel instead, and maybe try the # escapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that your problems stem from the fact that NSString's ASCII support is limited to a strict 7-bit ASCII encoding, which means only the chars 0-127 are supported.  You'll have to use a different data type to store your chars, and that different data type is `unichar`, which supports 2^15-1 precisely because it is `unsigned short`.  However, you will need to convert it to an NSString which operates in Unicode with this [category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1354413/945847):

```
@interface NSString (MNNSStringWithUnichar)
+ (NSString *) stringWithUnichar: (unichar) value;
@end

@implementation NSString (MNNSStringWithUnichar)

+ (NSString *) stringWithUnichar:(unichar) value {
     NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", value];
     return str;
}
@end
```

Or simply `NSLog(@"%C", value);`

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I go about this? Can I still use NSString or do need to use a different type? Can i just use stringWithUTF8String?

Comment: I've added an edit.  Note there are no guarantees as to the effectiveness of the character conversion.