# Converting NSString to unichar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, unichar

I have seen questions in stackoverflow that convert unichar to NSString but now I would like to do the reverse.

How do i do it?

Need some guidance.. Thanks

For example, I have an array of strings:`[@"o",@"p",@"q"];`

These are strings inside. How do i convert it back to unichar?

Comment: You mean an array of `unichar`? There's a method on `NSString` that will do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354388/unichar-and-nsstring-how-interchangeable-are-these)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following will work as long as the first character isn't actually two composed characters (in other words as long as the character doesn't have a Unicode value greater than \UFFFF):

```
unichar ch = [someString characterAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert it to a buffer in `NSData`:

```
if ([string canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]) {
    NSData * data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    const unichar* const ptr = (const unichar*)data.bytes;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this produce a different result than just casting the return value of `[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]`?

Comment: @SeamusCampbell the `NSData` variant is not terminated

Comment: Beware: this add a BOM which may or may not be desired!